# jQuery Dialog showing input item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have two boxes, "box1" contains listed items (text) and "box2" is empty. The objective is that the user can drag the items from box1 to box2, then press a button to register to open a dialog box. I got that working! But the problem is that I need the dialog box to show the items that have been dragged into box2.

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      draggable: false,
    });


    $( "#register" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
  });
 $(function() {

    $( "#box1 li" ).draggable({
      appendTo: "body",
      helper: "clone"
    });
    $( "#box2 ol" ).droppable({
      activeClass: "ui-state-default",
      hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
      accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).find( ".respondlist" ).remove();
        $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
      }
    }).sortable({
      items: "li:not(.respondlist)",
      sort: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
      }
    });
  });
```

I currently have no idea how to do it. Would be thankful if someone could help me out.

Edit: https://jsfiddle.net/Kasper_J/Lwqbbapu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on register. You can find all the `<li>` elements in `#box2 ol` and append it to `#dialog`. Do it after   `$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );` as when the dialog box is close its css has `display:none` and because of that you probably cannot add any element on it(probably).

you can do it something like below. (**Tested**)

```
$( "#register" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog("open");
  var newcontent = document.createElement('div');
  newcontent.innerHTML = $("#box2 ol").html();
  document.getElementById("dialog").appendChild(newcontent);
});
```

**Update:** I updated the solution (working). (thanks for the fiddle).

Here is the working fiddle : [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwqbbapu/2/)

---

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it doesn't seem to work, the dialog is still empty.

Comment: you can try the updated one. Also can you make a fiddle of your problem including your html. So that we can help more effectively.